# QUESTION about WOULD

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, modal-verbs

My friend said to me yesterday that "**I don't think having superpowers would make my life easier**". Why did he use **would** in that sentence?

It is not future in the past, so why use **would**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "I've just bought myself a Tesla but it **won't** make me a better driver." (expresses a prediction in the future using 'will'.)
2. "If I bought a Tesla, it **wouldn't** make me a better driver." (expresses a hypothetical/unreal situation)
3. I don't think having a Tesla **would** make me a better driver. (an unexpressed condition or an uncertain opinion).

In the OP's example

> I don't think having superpowers **would** make my life easier

could also be expressed as

1. If I had superpowers, it **would not** make my life easier (conditional)
2. In my opinion, having superpowers **would not** make my life easier (opinion)

### would

> 4. [used to say what you think someone should do or to ask for someone's opinion about what to do](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/would)
>
>    - If I were you, I would go to the hospital. [=I think that you should go to the hospital]
>    - I would take the train instead of driving into the city.
>    - I would turn back if I were you.
>    - What would you do in my situation?

Comment: so it is basically a conditional?

Comment: @lollel123 I've expanded my answer, it should be clearer now.